# Logout of Social Networks from iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ipad, cookies

In my app i am using Google, face book login. I was able to login properly but when i try to log out from Google , face book i am using following code.But my problem is even if i log out from my app.

When i click on login buttons it is asking permissions not login screen. Even if i log out from my app, Do i need to log out in safari browser (clear cookies in settings)  or device social apps, or do i need to do log out from Appdelegate.

What to do to complete logout from app it self.

```
[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];

//facebook
FBSession* session = [FBSession activeSession];
[session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[session close];
[FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSArray* facebookCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://facebook.com/"]];

for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in facebookCookies) {
    [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For FB, closeAndClearTokenInformation only logs the user out of your app, and not any other app (like the Facebook app, or Safari, if the user is logged in there).

When you do login again, it will fast-app-switch (to either the FB app or Safari), and if the user is still logged in there, it will just switch back and give your app an access token (unless you're asking for additional permissions). This is how SSO is supposed to work.